# How to connect a WPF app and it's database which placed on different servers

Tags: sql-server, wpf, publish

I have a WPF app and published it on a server with a valid Ip, it's database placed on another server (without valid Ip) which is connected to that server via LAN. Now, when I run the app from client pc, it raises an error about it can't connect to db. what can I do for this?

Comment: Have you checked that your db has access to the firewall. Maybe you need to set a group policy. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Comment: I got the problem :sql port is closed. is there any way to connect without opening sql port or using wcf ?